# Can't send push notification to Google Smart Display

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-assistant-sdk

I need to send push notifications to a Google Nest Hub.
I followed the docs from Google: https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications

The problem is that I can send notifications to smartphones but not to the smart display.

```
const request = require('request');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const key = require("./Jessa Assistent-730a994db178.json");

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email, null, key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'],
  null
);

jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
  if (!err) {
    request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
      auth: {
        bearer: tokens.access_token,
      },
      json: true,
      body: {
        customPushMessage: {
          userNotification: {
            title: 'Push Notification Title',
          },
          target: {
            userId: '<User_ID> (Took this part out of this example)',
            intent: 'High Priority Vragen',
            locale: 'nl-NL'
          },
        },
        isInSandbox: true,
      },
    }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
      console.log(`${httpResponse.statusCode}: ${httpResponse.statusMessage}`);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Smart displays do not support notifications.